# Problem with enumerate

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I am using `enumerate` (with the package `enumitem`) and want to make lists as in the example below.

```
Here is the first list: 
     1. Item 1.
     2. Item 2.
etc. 

Here is the second list: 
    (i) Item 1.
   (ii) Item 2.
  (iii) Item 3. This item is longer, to show how text should be aligned when it
        wraps after the end of a line.
```

Here is an MWE. Setting `labelindent` gives the desired text wrap, but the items won't be aligned. Setting `itemindent` aligns the items, but messes up the text wrap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent First the result by setting ``labelindent". Here is the first list: 
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, labelsep=1.0em, labelindent=\parindent, 
itemsep=0.0em, topsep=0.5em, label=\arabic*.]
    \item Item 1.
    \item Item 2.
\end{enumerate}
Here is the second list: 
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, labelsep=1.0em, labelindent=\parindent, 
itemsep=0.0em, topsep=0.5em, label=(\roman*)]
    \item Item 1.
    \item Item 2. 
    \item Item 3. This item is longer, to show how text should be aligned when it 
    wraps after the end of a line. 
\end{enumerate}
Notice how the items in the two lists are not the same distance from the left 
margin. 

Now the solution with by setting ``itemindent". Here is the first list: 
\begin{enumerate}[labelsep=1.0em, itemindent=\parindent, itemsep=0.0em, 
topsep=0.5em]
    \item Item 1.
    \item Item 2.
\end{enumerate}
Here is the second list: 
\begin{enumerate}[labelsep=1.0em, itemindent=\parindent, itemsep=0.0em, 
topsep=0.5em, label=(\roman*)]
    \item Item 1.
    \item Item 2. 
    \item Item 3. This item is longer, to show how text should be aligned when it 
    wraps after the end of a line. 
\end{enumerate}
Notice how the text in the various items is the same distance from the left margin, except 
in the last line of the    last item. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the usage of `widest*=somenumber` should be better, together with a special list clone.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\def\widestnumber{25}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mylist,1]{   
  leftmargin=40pt,
  labelsep=1.0em, %labelindent=\parindent, 
  itemsep=0.0em, 
  topsep=0.5em, 
  label=\arabic*.,
  widest*=\widestnumber}


\noindent First the result by setting "labelindent". Here is the first list: 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Item 1.
    \item Item 2.
\end{mylist}
Here is the second list: 
\begin{mylist}[label=(\roman*)]
    \item Item 1.
    \item Item 2. 
    \item Item 3. This item is longer, to show how text should be aligned when it 
    wraps after the end of a line. 
\end{mylist}
Notice how the items in the two lists are not the same distance from the left 
margin. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the need to clone it, you can just define a new enumitem key that sets all those settings at once. Very useful feature.

Comment: @daleif: Yes, that's true. I thought to provide another list rather to keep the usual 'enumerate' untouched

Comment: Can this be modified to allow for normal paragraphs within an item?

Comment: @RandyRanderson: That's another question

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281606/normal-paragraphs-in-a-certain-list-environment