# Normal paragraphs in a certain list environment

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\def\widestnumber{25}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mylist,1]{   
  leftmargin=40pt,
  labelsep=1.0em, 
  itemsep=0.0em, 
  topsep=0.5em, 
  label=\arabic*.,
  widest*=\widestnumber}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
   \item Here is a list item which consists of two paragraphs. This is the first paragraph. 

   Here is the second paragraph. I want it to have a normal indent at the beginning.
   \item Here is another item.
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that in Danie Els's answer you can just remove the color part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\def\widestnumber{25}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mylist,1]{
  leftmargin=40pt,
  labelsep=1.0em,
  itemsep=0.0em,
  topsep=0.5em,
  label=\arabic*.,
  widest*=\widestnumber, 
  listparindent =\parindent
  parsep=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
  \item Here is a list item which consists of two paragraphs. This is the first paragraph.

  Here is the second paragraph. I want it to have a normal indent at the beginning.
  \item Here is another item.
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a similar command to make the space between paragraphs the normal amount?

Comment: Yes: it is fixed by the value of `parsep=0pt`, if I understand well what you mean. Please check my updated answer.